# Fancybox iframe reload

Tags: javascript, redirect, fancybox

I need help! I use fancybox and use iframe to show other page but I have this code in iframe.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goSelect(selectobj){
 window.location.href='iframe.php?x='+selectobj
}
</script>
```

After I select other value this redirect but problem is that i need to redirect in fancybox not close and go to this page. How make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but with struts2.

I manage to do something like this, to open another page in a fancybox:

HTML:

```
<a class="inline" href="page">
Go
</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#inline, .inline").fancybox({
    'type':           'inline',
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,
    'autoScale':      false,
    'width':          '100%',
    'height':         '100%',
    'transitionIn':   'none',
    'transitionOut':  'none',
    'titleShow':      true,
    'titlePosition':  'outside'
});
```

Hope it helps you!